# Ambiguous action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

For a project I'm currently working on, I currently have 2 separate instances of users (might increase later): CorporateCustomer and PrivateCustomer.
Both inherit from the abstract class Customer.

To display the differences between these customers, currently 2 different views are created, which are rendered by the same Action in the following way:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Edit()
    {
            if(User.IsCorporate)
                return View("EditCorporate", new CorporateCustomer());
            else
                return View("EditPrivate", new PrivateCustomer());
    }
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(CorporateCustomer customer){...}
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(PrivateCustomer customer){...}
```

For just displaying information, this works like a charm. The urls are the same for each type, which is what we were aiming for.

However, when doing a post, I can only specify a single type, or risk running into an ambiguous action method (which makes sense, of course).

Now my question is: is there any elegant way to handle these 2 different types, while still retaining a single url? Or am I doomed to make the base class non-abstract and look up the values in the Request.Form collection?

Thanks if anyone can come up with a sollution (or just straight point out that what I'm doing is stupid and cannot be done)

Comment: What happens if you include both types as parameters on a single POST action? `Edit( CorporateCustomer c, PrivateCustomer p )`

Comment: @NicholasButler That works! Should've thought about it myself, but apparantly my brain doesn't work very well. Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: i agree with @NicholasButler, you can not have tow actionresult methods with same name and different parameter types. Try adding both parameters to one method and handle your logic in that method.

Comment: Although it works on a small scale, it doesn't help maintainability if his number of user types goes up, though. Just a general moan really as I to have had this pain before and wished that generics could be used in ActionResults and WCF Service Contracts - exposed footprints in general.

Comment: To clarify, you *can* have two action methods with the same name and different parameter types, but those parameters must be scalar (or rather at least one scalar must be involved). When your method accepts a model, the modelbinder is required to fill it in, which happens at runtime not compile time. In order to have method overloads, the compiler must be able to distinguish them at compile time.

Comment: @Kippie I've posted my suggestion as an answer - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have one Action that takes both parameter types.

The model binder should then fill them with whatever data is posted and you can figure out which is right in your Action method.

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit( CorporateCustomer c, PrivateCustomer p )
{
  ...
}
```